# Авторизация на сайте https

Tags: python, python-3.x, https

Всем привет!
Подскажите, кто ни будь делал скрипт авторизации на сайте https?
Пишу парсер сайта, точнее одной страницы, но перед этим нужно авторизоваться, как раз этот блок у меня не получается реализовать.
Как можно написать скрипт авторизации, если например есть HTTP reques, при котором авторизация проходит?
Скажу честно, в питоне я не силён, да и в программировании в общем.
Может есть у кого какие наработки?
Есть скрипт, но авторизация не проходит:

```
import requests
datas = {
'username':'def',
'password':'def',
'authType':'def'
}

username = input('Enter username: ')
password = input('password: ')
authType = input('authType: ')
datas['username'] = username
datas['password'] = password
datas['authType'] = authType
url = 'https://IP_addres/admin/LoginAction.do'
s = requests.Session()
loging = s.post(url, data = datas, verify=False)
f = open('result.txt','w+')
f.write(loging.text)
f.close()
```

PS: хочу авторизоваться на портале CISCO ISE

Comment: https://github.com/falkowich/ise#usage ? https://developer.cisco.com/docs/identity-services-engine/3.0/#!internal-users-get-all-users ?

Comment: @Violet, спасибо, но к сожалению это не то. В данных ресурсах запросы к RESTful API, а мне нужна авторизация другого типа(

Comment: посмотрите через инструмент разработчика в браузере (F12) тело запроса

Comment: @Violet походу там JS...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующие библиотеки:

- Selenium, Может хорошо притворяться браузером, рендерит JS, имитирует действия пользователя, но требует навыка. (Мне кажется это ваш вариант)
- BeautifulSoup4, Хлеб и соль парсинга сайтов. Но если страница рисуется JS то он вам не подойдет
- Scrapy, очень мощный фреймворк для парсинга.

Если вы не планируете развиваться как программист то наймите когонибудь на фриланс бирже что бы вам код написали. Это сэкономит много времени.
Если вы начинающий программист то это отличный способ потренироваться. Хотя притворяться пользователем не тривиальная задача.
В вашем случае помоч вам кодом сложно, потому что нужно смотреть в HTML код страницы и по тегам определять поля в которые нужно вставить логин и пассворд. Незная сайта и не имея учетки помоч вам сложно.
Желаю удачи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Эта задача не приоритетная, если не получится, значит не получится, я не собираюсь быть программистом, но опыт мне нужен)

Comment: Какие параметры передаются я уже выяснил)
Selenium это библиотека для python?

Comment: Да, вот дока https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ там и простые примеры есть. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage